# How does one create a read-only form layout in twitter bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

Suppose you have view information (not edit information) when using twitter bootstrap. What's the best way to display the data?

This was actually brought up as an issue: https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/issues/4094.

Comment: Might not be thinking this through but could you not just add 'disabled' to the form fields?

Comment: That's a totally different look with disabled editable fields.

Answer (score 13):

#### Bootstrap 3

BS3 has a concept of a **static** field.  You can mix and match static fields and input fields on the same form.  Or use all static fields for a read only form.

http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-controls-static

Instead of a normal `input` element, you can use a `p` tag with this special bootstrap class:

```
<p class="form-control-static">email@example.com</p>
```

#### Bootstrap 4:

You can use the `form-control-plaintext` class on an `input` tag.

See https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/forms/#readonly-plain-text

#### Boostrap 5:

[form-control-plaintext](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/forms/form-control/#readonly-plain-text)

Comment: for 4.0 it's form-control-plaintext https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/forms/?#readonly-plain-text

Answer (score 3):

I went along with MDO's answer on github.

Here's the example presented above that shows how to do this, using codepen. You can experiment with the styling. Pretty cool tool.

This also shows how to link to the bootstrap stylesheet in codepen.

http://cdpn.io/gFecv